# Code request: Make "copy formatted code" bulletproof

Tags: formatting, code-request, clipboard

With the `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` functions comes a usable code formatting engine. On this site, most of the time we share code. I believe it would be awesome to have a robust button that lets you copy selected code or cells directly to clipboard and make pasting more easy.

Look for instance at this small function:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
Button["Print Formatted Code",
    Print[
        DisplayForm[
            MakeFormattedBoxes @@ MakeExpression[CurrentValue["SelectionData"]]
        ]
    ]
]
```

It has some major flaws (it doesn't preserve strings, it adds contexts, etc..) but it gives a head start. With it, you can select a portion of code (not a cell) and get a reformatted version. The above code block was created with it.

It can turn this

```
{0.872454,0.687674,0.127934,0.544796,0.522242,0.699434,0.0290001,0.111096,0.904602,0.0470287,0.309469,0.664936,0.613936,0.256512,0.247723,0.0429109,0.275135,0.907288,0.381302,0.142904}
```

into this

```
{
    0.8724536302414463, 0.6876741664055988, 0.12793381311984442, 0.5447962818014034,
    0.5222421222710214, 0.6994341188236166, 0.02900006229926766, 0.11109627731891036,
    0.9046020599101727, 0.04702874732980167, 0.3094690356201151, 0.664935721568001,
    0.6139357391996489, 0.25651232073953256, 0.24772295896395002, 0.04291086493297902,
    0.2751346161611363, 0.9072882664480462, 0.3813024502288167, 0.14290372799071482
}
```

Not perfect, but a start.

**Question:** Can we create a robust "Copy code to clipboard" button that handles all use-cases and copies a reformatted version of the selection to the clipboard? It should not rely on additional packages (like Leonids code formatter) but it should reuse what is provided by the `` GeneralUtilities` `` package.

### Reformatting expressions

If we have the code as expression and not as `Cell[..]` we can look into the implementation of `MakeFormattedBoxes`. Especially the function

```
GeneralUtilities`Formatting`PackagePrivate`fullbox
```

is very interesting as it contains all rules that are applied to turn an expression into its reformatted box form. Spelunking there, we find how the reformatter

- includes context names in the code (`sn`)
- adjusts that `f[x]` is turned into `f@x` (`syntax`)
- make e.g. `Or` displayed as either `Or[..]` or `x||y`

Below is an image of the code, because SE breaks it with dollar variables. You can get the code with

```
Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsY34.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It appears I don't have `MakeFormattedBoxes` in version 10.1.0 but +1 for an interesting question!

Comment: Could you outline requirements for a valid answer? I'm not sure I got the point. Moreover, the fundamental problem with those tools is that they work with expressions (afaict) so no original choices about operators form used is preserved (`f[x]` vs `f@x` vs `f//x`). Another major issue is that comments will be stripped.